# C# Passing Variable to class, then returning class output in form

Tags: c#, class

I'm having a really tough time wrapping my head around how to pass data back and forth between classes. I have taken some college courses Introduction to OOP, Beginning C++, Beginning C# and gone through several self paced online tutorials. I believe I'm grasping when to use classes but not how to use them. So heres what I'm trying to do, I just need a little guidance on how to accomplish this. Please don't tell me to google because I have searched until my fingers bled (ok not literally) and just need something more to go on at this point such as specific terminology. If someone could explain to me in C# terms anyways it would be helpful as I will have something specific to start searching on again.

So here is where I'm at...

I wrote an app that puts everything into the same class (Form1) and have it working. I'm using values from a dropdown list that preform a database query and assigns some variables that I use to play a video.

Heres the my complete code all in Form1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;

namespace Tests
{
public partial class Tests : Form
{
    public Tests()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        using (var conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=TestDB.sdf;Password=;Persist Security Info=True"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            var comm = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT DISTINCT ColumnOne FROM main", conn);                
            SqlCeDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
                columnOneComboBox.Items.Add(reader["ColumnOne"]);
        }
    }

    private void columnOneComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        testsListBox.Items.Clear();
        testVideoMediaPlayer.Visible = false;

        var columnOne = columnOneComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
        using (var conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=TestDB.sdf;Password=;Persist Security Info=True"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            var comm = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM main WHERE ColumnOne='" + columnOne + "' ORDER BY ColumnTwo", conn);
            SqlCeDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
                testsListBox.Items.Add(reader["ColumnTwo"]);
        }
    }

    private void TestListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var columnTwo = testsListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
        using (var conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=TestDB.sdf;Password=Tr@1n!ng;Persist Security Info=True"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            var comm = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM main WHERE ColumnTwo='" + columnTwo + "'", conn);
            SqlCeDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.Read())
            {
                bodyPositionRichTextBox.Text = reader["ColumnThree"].ToString();
                techniqueRichTextBox.Text = reader["ColumnFour"].ToString();
                string videoPath = reader["Video"].ToString();

                if (videoPath != "")
                {
                    testVideoMediaPlayer.URL = @"Videos/" + videoPath;
                    testVideoMediaPlayer.settings.playCount = 1000;
                    testVideoMediaPlayer.uiMode = "none";
                    testVideoMediaPlayer.Visible = true;
                    testVideoMediaPlayer.stretchToFit = true;
                    testVideoMediaPlayer.fullScreen = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    testVideoMediaPlayer.Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Now, what I was thinking about doing is creating separate class called MediaPlayer but I need to use a variable from Form1 in the MediaPlayer class where all the video controls are specified then have From1 call that player. So the following is what I was thinking of moving to MediaPlayer.cs:

```
                if (videoPath != "")
                {
                    testVideoMediaPlayer.URL = @"Videos/" + videoPath;
                    testVideoMediaPlayer.settings.playCount = 1000;
                    testVideoMediaPlayer.uiMode = "none";
                    testVideoMediaPlayer.Visible = true;
                    testVideoMediaPlayer.stretchToFit = true;
                    testVideoMediaPlayer.fullScreen = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    testVideoMediaPlayer.Visible = false;
                }
```

Am I going about this the wrong way? I'm not getting how to pass the string variable "Videos" from Test.cs to MediaPlayer.cs or how to call the MediaPlayer.cs from Test.cs. Thanks for any guidance that can be offered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class MediaPlayer like this (substitute for your component type) :

```
public class MediaPlayer
{
    /* your video type */ TestVideoMediaPlayer { get; set; }

    public MediaPlayer(/* your video type */ testVideoMediaPlayer)
    {
        TestVideoMediaPlayer = testVideoMediaPlayer;
    }

    public void SetMediaPlayer(string url, int playerCount, string uiMode, bool visible, bool stretch, bool fullScreen)
    {
         if (url != "")
            {
                TestVideoMediaPlayer.URL = @"Videos/" + url;
                TestVideoMediaPlayer.settings.playCount = playerCount;
                TestVideoMediaPlayer.uiMode = uiMode;
                TestVideoMediaPlayer.Visible = visible;
                TestVideoMediaPlayer.stretchToFit = stretch;
                TestVideoMediaPlayer.fullScreen = fullScreen;
            }
            else
            {
                TestVideoMediaPlayer.Visible = false;
            }
    }
}
```

And substitute your call to:

```
 if (reader.Read())
 {
      bodyPositionRichTextBox.Text = reader["ColumnThree"].ToString();
      techniqueRichTextBox.Text = reader["ColumnFour"].ToString();
      string videoPath = reader["Video"].ToString();

      MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(testVideoMediaPlayer);
      mp.SetMediaPlayer(videoPath, 1000, "none", true, true, false);
 }
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for you quick and detailed sample code. This is a huge help for me in starting to understand how to pass information between classes.